# Hardware fault and hardware race condition- interrupts

Tags: x86, operating-system, interrupt-handling

In the 382 line in the file interrupt.c ( http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~sbansal/os/pintos/doc/pintos_html/interrupt_8c-source.html) I saw the comment:

> There is no handler, but this interrupt can trigger spuriously due to a hardware fault or hardware race condition.  Ignore it.

`hardware fault` and `hardware race condition`. What's going on?

Comment: Sounds like the person who wrote the comment doesn't know what's going on, either. For some reason, and they're guessing either a hardware fault or a hardware race condition, these particular interrupts get triggered. They don't know why. And they don't care; they just want to suppress them.

Comment: @CodyGray, I see that they want to suppress them. The more interesing issue is why the do it.

Comment: The hardware fault they are probably referring to is noise (this can happen on real hardware) on the interrupt or IRQ line that make it briefly appear as if there was an IRQ. When they say hardware race condition I think they used the wrong terminology but what they probably are speaking of is the scenario where an interrupt occurs and then it disappears because someone sent an end of interrupt request to the PIC controller when they shouldn't have. Both those things cause spurious interrupts. Problem though is that they do nothing, which is actually wrong!!

Comment: If you get a spurious external interrupt (you can check by querying the appropriate ISR) on IRQ7 for whatever reason you are not suppose to send an End of Interrupt (EOI) to the master PIC, yet when this code gets near the bottom it does just that. So that is a bug. If the external IRQ15 gets a spurious interrupt it is suppose to send an EOI to the master PIC only, but NOT the slave one. The code in Pintos is actually incorrect as they take no special action with regards to the EOIs. The fact they ignore it and treat it like a regular interrupt can cause problems.

Comment: "The hardware fault they are probably referring to is noise (this can happen on real hardware) on the interrupt or IRQ line that make it briefly appear as if there was an IRQ." My knowledge about electronic is a bit poor so it may raise a problem with understanding. Anyway, let's assume that a noise interrupt happened. How does the PIC ( or CPU, what exactly?) know that it is a spurious interrupt? I am reasoning that CPU ( PIC) knows it because IRQ is equal to `0x27` ( so it looks like a special IRQ line).I think I don't understand your second comment. Perhaps, I should be referenced somewhere

Comment: In simplest terms the PIC normally will get an external interrupt and then raise the interrupt line to the CPU. The CPU will in turn acknowledge that and wait for the PIC to send the CPU the IRQ number and the PIC sets the ISR flag for that IRQ. That can be queried by software. If a CPU receives noise on its interrupt line (not generated by the PIC), the PIC will get an unexpected request from the CPU for the IRQ number. Since the PIC doesn't know anything about it, it fulfills the request by telling it that a particular interrupt caused it (IRQ7 or IRQ15) but doesn't set the ISR flag

Comment: So a proper IRQ7 handler would query the ISR flag from the PIC for IRQ7 to see if it is actually set. If it is set then we know it is a real interrupt. If it is clear then we know it was a spurious interrupt. Similar thing for IRQ15 except you have to query the ISR flag on the slave PIC. Once you determine that you have to consider doing the right thing with the EOI as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: But the code in Pintos does none of that checking, so IMHO it actually handles spurious interrupts incorrectly (i'd discuss that with the professor)

Comment: OSDev Wiki appears to have a page with what I said, and a better overall description of how the 8259 interacts with the x86 processor. It seems to confirm what I said: http://wiki.osdev.org/8259_PIC . I would pay attention to the section about *ISR and IRR* and then read about *Spurious_IRQs* .

Comment: @MichaelPetch, thanks :)